# Script to start command in byobu tab

Tags: bash, tmux, ubuntu-server, gnu-screen, byobu

I have used screen to start a server process, to witch I can later attach if needed and deatach again to carry on with other things. It worked fine but I have found byobu recently and I really love it.

I want to use the same kind of scripts to run the server but instead of a screen sesson I would like to attach it to a byobu tab.

I'm using byobu-tmux (because it looks better). How could I do it?

My original scripts (they both do more, but these are the relevant parts):

```
# Startup  
screen -a -dmS <name> <command>

# Attach
screen -x <name>
```

I'm using Ubuntu server 16.04

Answer (score 11):

I don't know `screen` commands, so here is a quick sample commands for `byobu`:

To create new tabs (called screens) inside the current session you can:

```
byobu new-window "ls -la && sleep 5"
```

To start a new session (new byobu instance you can attach to) with a command you can:

```
byobu new-session -s "session name" "ls -la && sleep 5"
```

To create it already detached:

```
byobu new-session -d -s "session name" "ls -la && sleep 5"
```

To attach to a session by name:

```
byobu attach -t "session name"
```

Comment: When I use the first command, the screen/tab closes after the `sleep` command runs out. Is there a way to keep the window open?

Comment: You can wait for a character after your commands are done: `byobu new-session -s "session name" "ls -la && sleep 5; read -n1"` You press any key and it closes.

Comment: That is indeed better, thanks. Is there a way to keep it open indefinitely untill I manually close it?

Comment: I think this is what `read -n1` is going to do anyway, it will keep it open indefinitely until you press a key. I'm not sure what else do you mean.

Comment: Well, I would prefer if the window did not close after I press a command, so I could use it further.

Comment: Then add a `&& bash -l` or whatever shell you want to use to the command.