# Open byobu window with multiple screens running one command each?

Tags: makefile, tmux, byobu

I want to run multiple commands in the same terminal window, where each command attaches to the terminal stdout. How can I do it with byobu? (or tmux)

Answer (score 0):

See this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39075216/163415

You can open multiple "tabs" that will run your commands with `new-window`.